# PHP add class to <option> element within loop

Tags: php, html

How can I add a CSS class to each option within my code? This is the PHP code below, please see the screenshot below as to where the class property should be - how can I modify this code to add a class to every option?

```php
<?php 
    if($params->get('cat_select_type','0')==1){
        $cat_sel = '<select  class="inputbox" id="se'.$module->id.'_cat_0" name="se_cats[]" onchange="se'.$module->id.'_getFields(this.value);"><option value="">'.JText::_('PLEASE_SELECT_CATEGORY').'</option>';
        foreach($categories as $cat){ 
            $c_name = str_ireplace("'", "&apos;", $cat->name);
            for($lev=0;$lev<$cat->level;$lev++){
                $c_name ="- ".$c_name;
            }                       
            $cat_sel .= '<option value="'.$cat->id.'">'.$c_name.'</option>';
        }
        $cat_sel .= '</select>';
        echo $cat_sel;
    }else{
        $cat_sel = '<select  class="inputbox" id="se'.$module->id.'_cat_0" name="se_cats[]" onchange="se'.$module->id.'_new_cat(0,this.value,new Array());se'.$module->id.'_getFields(this.value);"><option value="">'.JText::_('PLEASE_SELECT_CATEGORY').'</option>';
        foreach($categories[0] as $cat){
            $cat_sel .= '<option value="'.$cat->id.'">'.str_ireplace("'", "&apos;", $cat->name).'</option>';
        }   
        $cat_sel .= '</select>';
        echo $cat_sel;
    }                   
?>
```

See image below:

[image: img]

Comment: Same way you add a class to any other elements. Where specifically are you having a problem? See [ask]

Comment: You probably want it on the `select`, not `option`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three instances within your code that where `<option>` elements appear within your select box, to add a CSS class to them you simply define it with the property `class`.

See all instances of `class="YOUR_CLASS_HERE"` within the code below.

```php
<?php 
    if ($params->get('cat_select_type','0') == 1) {
        $cat_sel = '<select  class="inputbox" id="se' . $module->id . '_cat_0" name="se_cats[]" onchange="se' . $module->id . '_getFields(this.value);"><option class="YOUR_CLASS_HERE" value="">' . JText::_('PLEASE_SELECT_CATEGORY') . '</option>';
        foreach($categories as $cat)
        { 
            $c_name = str_ireplace("'", "&apos;", $cat->name);
            for($lev=0; $lev < $cat->level; $lev++) {
                $c_name ="- " . $c_name;
            }

            $cat_sel .= '<option class="YOUR_CLASS_HERE" value="' . $cat->id . '">' . $c_name . '</option>';
        }

        $cat_sel .= '</select>';
        echo $cat_sel;
    } else {
        $cat_sel = '<select  class="inputbox" id="se' . $module->id . '_cat_0" name="se_cats[]" onchange="se' . $module->id . '_new_cat(0,this.value,new Array());se' . $module->id . '_getFields(this.value);"><option class="YOUR_CLASS_HERE" value="">' . JText::_('PLEASE_SELECT_CATEGORY') . '</option>';
        foreach($categories[0] as $cat) {
            $cat_sel .= '<option class="YOUR_CLASS_HERE" value="' . $cat->id . '">' . str_ireplace("'", "&apos;", $cat->name) . '</option>';
        }

        $cat_sel .= '</select>';
        echo $cat_sel;
    }                   
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me, but I want each option to have a different class from the other so I can change the CSS on each option by itself.

Comment: Each option is within a `foreach` loop, so you can add whichever class you want respectively. For adding specific classes, you are going to have to provide more information in terms of context as to how to determine what class needs to be added.

Comment: See this screenshot shows that all options have the same class
https://prnt.sc/23n7ux4

Comment: Yes, like I mentioned you need to specify the logic to add whatever classes you want to each option.

Comment: Can a class follow each value?

Comment: Yes, you can just output the variable holding the ID into the class.